# AWS RDS No route to host from Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I created a new RDS (Aurora MySQL) in AWS. For the security group, I selected the same security group that was used from a current production database (Aurora MySQL). The inbound rules are the same and include the IP of my Ubuntu server. I am able to successfully connect to the new RDS server locally, but am receiving the following error from my Ubuntu server:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

Both of the servers are in us-east-2 region. The only noticeable difference between the two is that the old server's writer instance is in us-east-2c and the new server is in us-east-2a. I've tried following most of the troubleshooting guides but have come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Availability zones 2c and 2a, make them in different subnets, check your route tables.

For testing open your Route Tables tab and associate the subnet in a2 with the Route table which was (probably still is) associated with the subnet in 2c

Comment: It was the availability zones that was causing the issue. Thank you so much for your help!